# Help with Seemingly Hopeless Double Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, physics

I hate to be that guy to just post an integration problem and ask how to solve it so I'll give a little relevant info

Okay, so I'm working on a physics project and my professor proposed that the following double integral could potentially solve a problem that I've used an alternative method to solve:

$$I=\int_0^\pi\int_0^\rho\frac{t^2\sin\phi\left(t\cos\phi-d\right)}{\left[t^2\sin^2\phi+\left(t\cos\phi-d\right)^2\right]^{3/2}}\;dt d\phi$$

1. $\rho$ is an arbitrary, strictly positive real constant
2. $d$ is a real constant that satisfies $d>\rho$

This integral's value could provide immense insight into fields of uniform, solid spherical objects, so it's actually pretty important for my work.

After some quick attempts to simplify, I decided to try some integral calculators with set values. Needless to say, the result after the first integral seemed so hopeless that I couldn't imagine simplifying and integrating again--not to mention then generalising constant inputs to their original variable form.

However, there is a strong likelihood that $I$ simplifies to one of the following two solutions:

$$\text{1.This solution comes from inverse square laws}$$

$$I=\frac{1}{d^2}$$

$$\text{2. This solution comes from a separate computation that I did (integrals below)}$$

$$I=\left(1-\frac{\rho^2}{5d^2}\right)\left[\frac{3}{2\rho^2}+\frac{3(\rho^2-d^2)}{4d\rho^3}\ln\left(\frac{d+\rho}{d-\rho}\right)\right]$$

Although it looks like these are vastly different answers, given $\rho=1$ and $d=10$, you get the following outputs from $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$1.\; I=0.01$$
$$2.\; I\approx 0.01000046$$

Here's the ratio of solution (2) over (1) for $\rho\in(0,1),\;d\in(0,50)$

[image: Solution Comparison]

I tried to tackle this problem differently than my professor, and set up the following integrals to solve the problem that lead to solution $(2)$:

$$\frac{9}{4\rho^6}\left[\;\int\limits_{d-\rho}^{d+\rho}x\left[x-\frac{x^2+d^2-\rho^2}{2d}\right]\left[\frac{(x+d)^2-\rho^2}{4d\cdot x}\right]\;dx\right]\cdot\left[\;\int\limits_{d-\rho}^{d+\rho}\frac{\rho^2-(x-d)^2}{2d\cdot x}\;dx\right]$$

---

*Where you come in*

If the double integral is correctly composed (which my professor felt confident with), **I need someone skilled in integration to solve said double integral**. I've given two possible solutions and it's probable that the answer will be one of those. If it's solution $(1)$, I know that mine will have an error and you will essentially have proved the inverse square law for gravitational and electric fields. If it's solution $(2)$, then this will be far more exciting to me but less likely. If it's neither, then there are several possible implications

**BOUNTY**

I'm willing to award the following bounties for solving the double integral at the beginning. Since certain solutions have stronger implications (as explained above), I'm rewarding the following bounties:

1. +200 rep if you verify solution $(1)$
2. +500 rep if you verify solution $(2)$
3. +75 rep for any other solutions (note they'll have to be verified by a second user first)

**QUESTIONS**

If you have any additional questions feel free to ask, and thanks for reading all this!

Comment: Edited: Typo in the original post

Comment: So $\phi\in[0,\pi]$, and $t\in[0,\rho]$ for some ?fixed? constant $\rho$? (And the first solution seems to not depend on $\rho$. Unexpected, since i can take $\rho=0$.) Please fix some framework for all used constants. Things seem to be important, please just fix these details for the eye of a first reader... Help will come in some seconds... (At least numerically, this is the easiest (experimental) validation when explicit choices are given.)

Comment: @dan_fulea Updated, here's what I added: 1. $\rho$ is an arbitrary, strictly positive constant and 2. $d$ is a positive real that satisfies $d>\rho$. Thanks for catching that

Comment: As @dan_fulea said the first solution should depend on $\rho$. The integral $I$ will be easier if you swap the order of integration, with the limits changing or not changing depending on the geometry of the problem. For example changing the order of integration without changing limits I get the answer $I=-\frac{2\rho^3}{3d^2}$. If this is correct I wonder why a factor of $\pi$ or $2\pi$ is missing, depending on whether the full integral is evaluated over a hemispherical space or a spherical space.

Comment: @JamesArathoon Interesting, that makes me think that there may be a typo in my professor's integral. Should I explain his approach so we can try to find a mistake because that solution doesn't make sense in context of the problem. The solution should hover around $1/d^2$ for any $d,\rho$ that meet the specifications

Comment: @LanierFreeman I'm not sure if this is too helpful, but I think the result *must* depend on rho. If you call the integral $I= I(\rho,d)$, then differentiate with rho, I got $I'= -2(\frac{\rho}{d})^{2}$, again, differentiated in rho. But this means that the original integral can't depend only on $d$, right?

Comment: @JamesArathoon that seems very correct to me. I started by diffetentiateing the integral in rho (see my above comment), and that would correctly coincide with the derivative of your answer with rho.

Comment: @JamesArathoon No, that's very helpful. When I started this problem I was first inspired by thinking the solution should depend on $\rho$ and not just $d$. The idea is that we have some point--we'll call it $p$--that is $d$ units from the centre of a solid sphere of radius $\rho$ and uniform density. Consider any arbitrary point inside the sphere. The idea is we sum up the inverse square of the distance from $p$ to each point in the sphere along the vector from the sphere's centre to $p$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes this is the type of integration found in some older textbooks on electromagnetism; the aim would be to eventually calculate the magnetic moment of a "classical" spinning electron, say if its charge is uniformly distributed over a spherical volume of radius $d$.

Comment: If it still matters, I also found the answer to be $\frac{-2\rho^3}{3d^2}$ by converting to rectangular.

Comment: I’m currently compiling a Mathematica image giving the ratio of the second solution to the first and will post it shortly. I’ve also written a java program that inputs $d$ and $\rho$ and outputs comparisons of (1) and (2). I can provide that to help show how your values compare to mine. I’ve found as d approaches rho, (2) is slightly higher than (1), and they hover around the exact same outputs for d significantly larger than rho

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a mathematician, I would divide by force in the numerator and denominator by $d^3$, substitute $t/d$ by something, thus reducing to the case $d=1$. But here, let it be, we conserve the homogeneous setting as a control of the computations.

---

We split the numerator, compute first 
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_1
&=
\int_0^\rho
dt
\int_0^\pi
\frac
{t^2\sin\phi\cdot t\cos\phi}
{\left[t^2\sin^2\phi+\left(t\cos\phi-D\right)^2\right]^{3/2}}\; d\phi
\\
&=
\int_0^\rho
dt
\int_0^\pi
\frac
{t^2(-\cos\phi)'\cdot t\cos\phi}
{\left[t^2-2Dt\cos\phi+D^2\right]^{3/2}}\; d\phi
\\
&\qquad\text{ Substitution: }u=\cos \phi\ ,
\\
&=
\int_0^\rho
dt
\int_{-1}^1
\frac
{t^3\; u}
{\left[t^2-2Dt\;u+D^2\right]^{3/2}}\; du
\\
&\qquad\text{ Substitution (for $u$, fixed $t$) of the radical }v=\sqrt{t^2-2Dt\;u+D^2}\ ,
\\
&\qquad u=\frac 1{2Dt}(t^2+D^2-v^2)\ ,\ du=-\frac v{Dt}\; dv\\ ,
\\
&=
-
\int_0^\rho
dt
\int_{\sqrt{t^2+2Dt+D^2}}^{\sqrt{t^2-2Dt+D^2}}
\frac
{t^3\; \frac 1{2Dt}(t^2+D^2-v^2)}
{v^3}\; \frac v{Dt}\; dv
\\
&=
\int_0^\rho
t\;dt
\int_{D-t}^{D+t}
\frac 1{2D^2}
\cdot
\frac {t^2+D^2-v^2}
{v^2}\; dv
\\
&=
\int_0^\rho
t\;dt
\;\frac 1{2D^2}
\left[
-(t^2+D^2)\frac 1v
-1
\right]_{v=D-t}^{v=D+t}
\\
&=
\int_0^\rho
dt
\;\frac t{2D^2}
\left[
(t^2+D^2)\left(\frac 1{D-t}-\frac 1{D+t}\right)
-
2t
\right]
\\
&=
\int_0^\rho
dt
\left[
\frac D{D+t}
+\frac D{D-t}
-2\frac{D^2+t^2}{D^2}
\right]
\\
&=
D\ln\frac {D+t}{D-t}
-
2\rho\left(1+\frac {\rho^2}{3D^2}\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Computer check for $D=2$, $\rho=1$ (pari/gp code):

```
? D=2; r=1;
? intnum(t=0,r, intnum(s=0, Pi, t^2*sin(s)*t*cos(s) / (t^2-2*t*D*cos(s)+D^2)^(3/2) ) )
%19 = 0.030557910669552716123823807178384744388
? D*log( (D+r)/(D-r) ) - 2*r*(1+r^2/3/D^2)
%20 = 0.030557910669552716123823807178384742634
? 
? D=223; r=101;
? intnum(t=0,r, intnum(s=0, Pi, t^2*sin(s)*t*cos(s) / (t^2-2*t*D*cos(s)+D^2)^(3/2) ) )
%22 = 1.9969022076015148346071622544965636670
? D*log( (D+r)/(D-r) ) - 2*r*(1+r^2/3/D^2)
%23 = 1.9969022076015148346071622544965636629
```

---

The other integral. I will integrate here first w.r.t. $t$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
J_2
&=
-D
\int_0^\pi
d\phi
\int_0^\rho
\frac
{t^2}
{\left[(t-D\cos\phi)^2+D\sin^2\phi\right]^{3/2}}
\; dt
\\
&\qquad\text{ and we consider separately (without the factor $-D$)}
\\
J_2(\phi)
&=
\int_0^\rho
\frac
{t^2}
{\left[(t-D\cos\phi)^2+D\sin^2\phi\right]^{3/2}}
\; dt
\\
&=
\int_{0-D\cos\phi}^{\rho-D\cos\phi}
\frac
{(u+D\cos\phi)^2}
{(u^2+a^2)^{3/2}}
\; du\ ,\qquad a:= D\sin\phi
\ .
\\
&\qquad
\text{ Now the integrals can be computed}
\\
\int \frac{u^2}
{(u^2+a^2)^{3/2}}
\; dt
&=
-\frac t{(u^2+a^2)^{1/2}}+\operatorname{arcsinh} \frac ta+C\ ,
\\
\int \frac{u}
{(u^2+a^2)^{3/2}}
\; dt
&=
-\frac 1{(u^2+a^2)^{1/2}}+C\ ,
\\
\int \frac{1}
{(u^2+a^2)^{3/2}}
\; dt
&=
-\frac {a^2\;u}{(u^2+a^2)^{1/2}}+C\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and the computation goes on.
If my calculus is ok, then 
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_2(\phi)
&=
\int_0^\pi
d\phi\;
\Bigg[
\operatorname{arcsinh} \frac{t-D\cos \phi}{D\sin\phi}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad+
\frac{t-D\cos\phi}{(t^2-2Dt\cos\phi+D^2)^{1/2}\sin^2\phi}
\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
+\frac2{(t^2-2Dt\cos\phi+D^2)^{1/2}}
\Bigg]_0^\rho\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
I have to submit, hope this is helpful to check with the own computations.
I'll be back, but typing kills a lot of time.

Comment: Sorry, been away. I've added a bounty of +100 to the question. Your answer is fantastic and I'll award one within a week. However, I'm leaving it up to attract other answers as well. Thanks for all the effort

Comment: Shouldn't the integrand in $J_2$ be $t^2 \sin \phi/((t - D \cos \phi)^2 + D^2 \sin^2 \phi)^{3/2}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

With the change of variable $u=\cos\phi$, the integral on $\phi$ becomes

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{t^2(tu-d)}{\sqrt{(u-dt)^2+d^2(1-t^2)}}du.$$

By decomposition of the numerator, you will get a term

$$c(t)\log((u-dt)^2+d^2(1-t^2))$$

and another

$$c'(t)\arctan\frac{u-dt}{d\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

These terms do not simplify at the bounds of the integration interval.

The integral on $t$ (cubic in $t$ at the denominator) is worse. I am not optimisitc about existence of a closed-form.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
&\iint \frac{t^2 \sin(\phi) (t \cos(\phi) - d)}{(t^2 \sin^2(\phi) + (t \cos(\phi) - d)^2)^{3/2}} \,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\phi  \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{d^2 + t^2 - 2 d t \cos(\phi)}(d^2 - 2 t^2 - 2 d t \cos(\phi) - 3 d^2 \cos(2 \phi))}{6d^2} \\
&+ d \cos(\phi) \ln\left(t - d \cos(\phi) + \sqrt{d^2 + t^2 - 2 d t \cos(\phi)}\right) \sin^2(\phi)  \text{,} \end{align*}
as one can readily verify.  Then $I = \frac{-2 \rho^3}{3 d^2}$.

I think for your case $1$, you mean $I \propto \frac{1}{d^2}$.  The integral can't be positive because:

- $t^2 \geq 0$ and
- $\sin(\phi) \geq 0$ since $\phi \in [0,\pi]$, but
- $t \cos(\phi) - d < 0$ because $0 < t < \rho < d$, while
- the denominator is $\geq 0$, so
- the integrand is (zero or) negative everywhere.

Comment: My prof said there may be a sign error so I’m not really bothered by that. Also the limit as $d\to\infty$ should lead to $1/d^2$ which I just realised and could inspire solutions and offer insight. I’ll get back within the coming days I have an exam to prepare for

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, that the solution of I looks similar to (1), it is:

$$I=-\frac{2 \rho ^3}{3 d^2}$$

I integrate the integral for several values of $\rho$ and $d$ numerical and checked this result, it is correct.

For the calculation you only need the substitution of @Yves it is not that difficult! - with the help of Mathematica:

First you have to do the integration over t, the antiderivative is just:\,

$\int \frac{t^{2}\text{Sin}[\phi ](t\text{Cos}[\phi ]-d)}{\left( t^{2}\ \text{
Sin}[\phi ]^{2}+(t\text{Cos}[\phi ]-d)^{2}\right) ^{3/2}}dt$

$=\frac{\left( 2\left( \rho ^{2}+3\varrho ^{2}\right) \text{Cos
}[\phi ]+\varrho \left( -4\rho +\sqrt{\rho ^{2}+\varrho ^{2}-2\rho \varrho 
\text{Cos}[\phi ]}\,\text{Log}\left[ \rho -\varrho \text{Cos}[\phi ]+\sqrt{
\rho ^{2}+\varrho ^{2}-2\rho \varrho \text{Cos}[\phi ]}\right] +\text{Cos}
[2\phi ]\left( -6\rho +3\sqrt{\rho ^{2}+\varrho ^{2}-2\rho \varrho \, \text{Cos}
[\phi ]}\,\text{Log}\left[ \rho -\varrho \text{Cos}[\phi ]+\sqrt{\rho ^{2}
+\varrho ^{2}-2\rho \varrho \text{Cos}[\phi ]}\right] \right) \right)
\right) \,\text{Sin}[\phi ]}{2\sqrt{\rho ^{2}+\varrho ^{2}-2\rho \varrho \text{
Cos}[\phi ]}}$

Second you do the substitution:

$$y=\text{Cos}[\phi ]$$
and the simplification:

$$\text{Cos}[2 \phi ]=\text{Cos}^{2}[\phi ]-\text{Sin}^{2}[\phi ]$$

leading to:

$$I=\int_{1}^{-1}\left[ \frac{-t \varrho +6y^{2} t\varrho -y\left( t^{2}+3\ \varrho ^{2}\right) +\left( 1-3y^{2}\right) \varrho \,\sqrt{t^{2}-2 \,y \,t \varrho +\varrho ^{2}}\,\text{Log}\left[ t -y\,\varrho +\sqrt{
t^{2}-2\,y\, t\, \varrho \ +\varrho ^{2}}\right] }{\sqrt{t^{2}-2\,y\, t
\varrho +\varrho ^{2}}}\right] _{0}^{\rho }dy$$

Mathematica even finds the antiderivative of that function, I guess it should be found also in a table of integrals. Then the expression can be simplified in a way so the stated result is given.